# Does local storage .length measure the length of the storage or the number of ids?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a login form using local storage. I've narrowed the issue down to either on the first or second line. To be totally honest, I'm not comfortable using .includes or .key. Thanks.

```js
if (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  if (localStorage.key(i).includes(username.value) != true) {
    if (username.value != "") {
      console.log("Your account has been created")
      localStorage.setItem(i, username.value)
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: Per https://javascript.info/localstorage - "length – the number of stored items".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to store the list of usernames in localStorage, I will suggest you to store it in the form of JSON data as mentioned below rather than creating multiple key value pairs for each new users.

[image]

**Add username to LocalStorage:**

```
if(username.value !== '')
{
  if(localStorage["users"])
  {
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]);
    users.push(username.value);
    localStorage["users"] = JSON.stringify(users);
  }
  else
  {
    localStorage["users"] = JSON.stringify([username.value]);
  }
}
```

**Get all username from LocalStorage:**

```
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]);
```

**Get username by name from LocalStorage:**

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]).find(u => u === username.value);
```

**Check if user exists**

```
let isUserExists = localStorage["users"] && JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]).some(u => u === username.value);
```

**Final Code:** You can use the below code.

```
if(username.value !== '')
{
  let isUserExists = localStorage["users"] && JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]).some(u => u === username.value);
  if(!isUserExists)
  {
    if(localStorage["users"])
    {
      let users = JSON.parse(localStorage["users"]);
      users.push(username.value);
      localStorage["users"] = JSON.stringify(users);
    }
    else
    {
      localStorage["users"] = JSON.stringify([username.value]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if you do that the previous usernames reset right?

Comment: I figured it out